# Convert integers to char arrays(byte's)

Tags: int

**UPDATE:**
I can do it easily from bytes to integers, but the current way I'm doing it seems to not be working so well.

Here's my current code:

```
static unsigned char* Int32ToBytes(signed int n)
{
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
        bytes[3-i] = (n & (255 << (i*8))) >> (i*8);
    return bytes;
}
```

I'm using this to write the bytes:

```
fwrite(Int32ToBytes(-1), 1 , 4 , file );
```

It's outputting: `FB 9C 8B 28` when I want it to output `FF FF FF FF` (signed ints).

Any ideas? Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be someting like bytes[3-i] = n & (255 << (i*8)) ?

Comment: idk that's why I asked here xD When doing that I got 0C 1C C7 46

Comment: I missed something, try this bytes[3-i] = (n & (255 << (i*8))) >> (i*8). Btw what language are you using?

Comment: C/C++ is my language. and nope still no luck :(

Comment: also I think what code you're using just does n & 255 lol.

Comment: n & 255 only get the latest 8 byte, you can do n & 255 but need to shift right the n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems work for me 
http://ideone.com/o6Llf9

```
void process(int x)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
    {
        unsigned char res = (x & (255 << (i*8))) >> (i*8);
        printf("%x " ,res);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    while (scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF) process(n);
    return 0;
}
```

something like this will also work

```
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
{
     bytes[3-i] = n & 255
     n = n >> 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/
It turns int to char. Example:
`int test; char buffer[33]; itoa(test, buffer, 10)`. You need to include stdlib.h.

Comment: alright does it support the difference between signed and unsigned? and how do you convert the str to a char array of 4 bytes long?

Comment: It should support signed/unsigned ints. I thought the question was on how to convert int to char? Anyway, I am assuming you are talking about an std::string object. Please clarify your question.