# Hexadecimal to string conversion in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, hex

Say I have a long value 3074109543
I need to convert this to hexadecimal which gives b73b3067(32 bits).

I am trying to represent this hexadecimal value in a string format which takes no more than 4 bytes.

Is it possible to represent b7 in 1st byte, 3b in 2nd byte, 30 in 3rd byte and so on, after the conversion to string.
I am working on the logic in C++ with bitwise operations and could think of anything  worthy enough. 
Kindly suggest some pseudo codes.

Comment: Look up converting an int to a char[4], eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858256/convert-integers-to-char-arraysbytes

Comment: You're not getting 2 digits per byte *and* string-format at the same time. You already *have* two digits per byte in your numeric representation (or at least its highly likely, anyway). If you want it in string-format you're going to pay the price of one digit per `char`, effectively doubling your required storage size (not including a terminator).

Comment: also, 3074109543/b73b3067 won't fit in a 32 bit long, unless you meant a unsigned long :)

Comment: How can one expect to fit the string "b73b3067" into a string of "no more than 4 bytes"? Stating it that way already contains a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A single hexadecimal character represents 4 bits.  A byte in C++ is at least 8 bits.  So you need at least 2 characters to represent a single byte in hexadecimal.  That's basic mathematics, and there's no way around it.  If your `long` is 4 bytes, then you need at least 8 characters (bytes), and if your `long` is 8 bytes, you need at least 16 characters.  (On machines where `long` is one byte, a byte must be at least 32 bits, so you need at least 8 characters to represent a single byte.)

Comment: +1 First sentence I think you meant *digit*; not character. I may be wrong on that, however.

Comment: A hexadecimal character will be a digit.  I wanted to insist on the fact that is a character, since the fact that it occupies 8 bits is critical to the rest of my argument.

Comment: Ok. Rereading the *second* sentence made that gel. sry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    unsigned int x = 3074109543;

    std::cout << x << '\t';

    std::string s( sizeof( unsigned int ), '\0' );

    std::generate( s.rbegin(), s.rend(), 
        [=] () mutable ->char { char c = 0xFF & x; x >>= 8; return c; } );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        char c1 = ( c & 0xF0 ) >> 4;
        c1 += c1 < 10 ? '0' : 'A' - 10;
        std::cout << c1;
        c1 = c & 0x0F;
        c1 += c1 < 10 ? '0' : 'A' - 10;
        std::cout << c1;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

3074109543      B73B3067

And the reverse operation

```
    x = std::accumulate( s.begin(), s.end(), 0u,
        [](unsigned int acc, char c ) { return ( ( acc << 8 ) | c ); } );

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Comment: Nice answer in general; overly complicated with use of C++11 features in my opinion as the OP seems to be new to C/ C++.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow -- Isn't the value of "c1" getting overwritten here??

Comment: I have not understood what you mean. c1 is formed to get the character representation of a hexadecimal value. c1 is a local variable that is used for the corresponding conversion to output internal representation of a hexadecimal digit on console.

Comment: I appreciate the logic applied here. But as per the question I was thinking if it is possible to represent b7 in 1st byte, 3b in 2nd byte, 30 in 3rd byte and so on. and later on store this value in a string containing not more than 4 bytes.

Comment: I showed relevant code. I think it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to represent [b73b3067 hex] in a string format which takes no more than 4 bytes.
>
> Is it possible to represent b7 in 1st byte, 3b in 2nd byte, 30 in 3rd byte and so on, after the conversion to string.

Not if you use the normal meaning of "string" as being some printable, human-readable text.  **If you put b7 in the first byte, 3b in the 2nd etc you've just recreated the binary number you started with** - albeit possibly with the byte order changed.  There's nothing meaningfully "string"-like about this... you can't write it to a terminal or file then read it as we can read "b73b3067" on the screen.  If you're confused about this distinction, you might want to read about ASCII character encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

To get a readable string representation of a number, you can use an out stream such as `std::cout` or `std::ostringstream`, the IO manipulator function `std::hex`.  Google `std::setw` and/or `std::setfill` too if you want a specific width and initial fill/padding character, e.g. 8 and '0' for "000012CD".

```
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << std::hex << my_number;
```